# What is equivalent of mysql_insert_id(); using prepared statement?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I have used prepared statement to insert an order into an orders table but now I want to insert the order items into the order items table based on the last ID inserted in the orders table:

```
if (isset($_POST['process'])) {

    $order_name = $_POST['order_name'];
    //create initial order
    $stmt = $conn2->prepare("INSERT INTO orders (order_name) VALUES (?)");
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $order_name);
    $stmt->execute();

    //this gets the most recent auto incremented ID from the database - this is the order_id we have just created
    $order_id = mysql_insert_id();

    //loop over all of our order items and add to the database
    foreach ($_SESSION['order'] as $item) {
```

What is equivalent to `mysql_insert_id();` using prepared statement?

Comment: What is mysql_insert_id(); in prepared statement style?

Comment: You mean, what is the equivalent of `mysql_insert_id` in the PDO library? Something wrong with [the documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php)?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're using PDO, it's [`PDO::lastInsertId()`](http://php.net/pdo.lastinsertid). So if your database handle is called `$link`:

```
$order_id = $link->lastInsertId();
```

If you're using MySQLi, it's [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/mysqli.insert_id) or `mysqli_insert_id()`:

```
$order_id = $link->insert_id;
```

Comment: but im using prepared statements with mysqli not PDO

Comment: @user1227124: Then it's [`mysqli::$insert_id`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php) or `mysqli_insert_id()`.

Comment: @user1227124: Next time, please just look it up in the documentation. We expect prior research in SO questions.

Answer (score 3):

You can try `$stmt->insert_id` to get inserted id