# MySQL - how to know the auto increment id of row

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, auto-increment

I want to insert data into a mysql database with orders for my site.

So i store the username and an auto increment order number in the database.

The question is, how i extract the order number out again.

I have tried this:

```
SELECT ordernumber FROM transactions WHERE.....
```

How to finsh this?

Comment: you want to get last inserted id from database

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

more info on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id

Note that you cannot use the C API function to retrieve the value for LAST_INSERT_ID(expr) after executing other SQL statements like SELECT or SET. So when you do INSERT Statement and just after that you do

```
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

it works but when there are other statements in the middle it will return 0 and the only way to get it is described bellow.

the other option is to sort DESC the table and get the first number

```
SELECT ordernumber FROM transactions ORDER By ordernumber DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

just use mysql_insert_id function it will give you last inserted id.

Answer (score 0):

call mysql_insert_id() function after the insert query executed code

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what methods you are using to insert the data into the database.

For mysql_* functions, you can use the mysql_insert_id() function.

For PDO use and mysqli_*, see this answer: [What is equivalent of mysql_insert_id(); using prepared statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753720/what-is-mysql-insert-id-using-prepared-statement)

Answer (score 0):

can also use LAST_INSERT_ID() or  mysql_insert_id

Answer (score 0):

```
$lastOrderNumber = mysql_insert_id();
$sql = "SELECT ordernumber FROM transactions WHERE ordernumber = $lastOrderNumber;";
```

Answer (score 0):

As said in the other answers you should use mysql_insert_id.

For example you can use this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('username')";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
echo "ID of last inserted record is: " . mysql_insert_id();
```

The above will output this:

```
ID of last inserted record is: (The ordernumber here)
```

For more info about mysql_insert_id you can take a look [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_insert_id.asp)

Answer (score 0):

there is a function to know what was the last id inserted in the current connection

for example after inster data you can get as below

```
mysql_query('INSERT INTO transactions  VALUES(\'b\')');

$id = mysql_insert_id();
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to run a query

```
select max(ordernumber) as lastordernumber from transactions;
```

here, lastordernumber is the desired value.