# How to insert two records into different tables first one with insert and then with select from the insert php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, forms

My question is not easy to explain for myself, but I will train.

I can insert a record into a table´s column form a form with php to mysql without problems. This insert generates an `auto_increment` record in another column from the same table.

So I want to select this new `auto_increment` record and `insert` it in another table.

```
<?php
            // process form`enter code here`
            $db_host="myhost";
            $db_user="myuser";
            $db_password="mypassword";
            $db_name="mydbname";
            $db_table_name="table1";
            $db_table_name2="table2";

            $record1= utf8_decode($_POST['record1']);
            $record2= utf8_decode($_POST['redord2']);

            $db_connection = mysqli_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_password,$db_name);

            if (!$db_connection) {
                die('Could not connect to the database');
            }
            //insert record1 into table1
            $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`name`) VALUES ("' . $record1 . '")';

            $result1 = $db_connection->query($insert_value);

            //consult auto_increment column from table1
            $select_value = 'SELECT column FROM table1 WHERE name = "' . $record1 . '"';

           //insert record2 into table2 in a row where a column is like $record1 
            $insert_value2 = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name2.'` (`column1, column2`) VALUES ("' . $record2. '","' . $select_value  . '") WHERE name = "'.$db_table_name2.'"';

            $result2 = $db_connection->query($select_value);

            mysqli_close($db_connection);

        ?>
```

Comment: are you referring to the last inserted id? check this link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query="Insert Statement";
$RunQuery = $db_connection->prepare($query);
```

If you're using PDO, it's PDO::lastInsertId(). So if your database handle is called $link:

```
$LastID = $db_connection->lastInsertId();
```

Or, If you're using MySQLi, it's mysqli::$insert_id or mysqli_insert_id():

```
$LastID = $db_connection->insert_id;
```

Now, Use this $LastID in next Query.

For more info, check [mysql_insert_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753720/what-is-mysql-insert-id-using-prepared-statement), [mysql_query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12310238/php-changing-old-mysql-query-to-pdo) in PDO

```
$insert_value2 = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name2.'` (`column1, column2`) VALUES ("'.$record2.'","'.$LastID.'") WHERE name = "'.$db_table_name2.'"';

$result2 = $db_connection->query($insert_value2);
```

Comment: Danish Enam, Thank you so much.

With your answer I check mysql_:insert_id is working. But my main problem is when I want to use $LastID to insert int the table2. I can´t

Comment: because, you are using $result2 = $db_connection->query($select_value);
$select_value here. USE $insert_value2 inside like this query($insert_value2); @Acicate

Comment: Check My Edited Answer Mr @Acicate

Comment: I try to use this, but doesn´t work:

$insert_value2 = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name2.'` (`column1, column2`) VALUES ("' . $record2  . '","' . $LastID  . '" ) WHERE name = "'.$db_table_name2.'"';

$db_connection->query($insert_value2);

Comment: @Acicate Copy This exactly code which i've given now and replace your existing code  $insert_value2 = "INSERT INTO '.$db_name.'.'.$db_table_name2.'(column1, column2) VALUES ('".$record2."','".$LastID."')
WHERE name = '".$db_table_name2."'";

Comment: Is not working :(. When I update the tables on Mysql I can see only the new record in the table1, but no in the table2

Comment: check here $record2= utf8_decode($_POST['redord2']); Check in your code, is redord2 or record2. Which is correct.
$record2= utf8_decode($_POST['record2']); @Acicate
$_POST['redord2'] or $_POST['record2' ??

Comment: There is mistake in your code only. never write confusing codes/query @Acicate

Comment: You was right!! Thank you. But In the case I wanted to use my single query result like a $variable. How can I do that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89643/discussion-between-nana-partykar-and-acicate).

Answer (score 0):

The `mysqli_insert_id()` function returns the ID generated by a query on a table with a column having the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute.

If the last query wasn't an INSERT or UPDATE statement or if the modified table does not have a column with the AUTO_INCREMENT attribute, this function will return zero.

For example,

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");
$query = "INSERT INTO myCity VALUES (NULL, 'Stuttgart', 'DEU', 'Stuttgart', 617000)";
$mysqli->query($query);
echo $mysqli->insert_id;
```

Comment: Insane Skulll, Thank you so much.

With your answer I check mysql_:insert_id is working. But my main problem is when I want to use $LastID to insert int the table2. I can´t

Comment: this will give you last inserted id, and u can use it for second query.