# Get id of last inserted prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, prepared-statement

How to get the id of the last inserted query using prepared statement ?

I wrote some PHP but I only get "0" as a result.
I tried to use the answer from this question : [Similar question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9753720/what-is-equivalent-of-mysql-insert-id-using-prepared-statement)

```
$locationName = $_GET['locationName'];
$locationResume = $_GET['locationResume'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO location (locationTitle, locationResume) VALUES (?,?);";
if ($locationName != null && $locationResume != null ) {

    if ($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) {
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $locationName, $locationResume);
        $locationId = $con->insert_id;

        #$locationId = $con->execute();
        echo $locationId;
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can get last_insert_id only after query execution.

Comment: You never execute so there is nothing inserted. When in doubt see the manual, http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php.

Comment: @vuliad Thank you, I thought it executed at the same time.. (like mysqli_insert_id()) You can post an an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get last_insert_id only after query execution.